# MySQL: All tables OK but still ERROR 1577 (system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged)

Tags: mysql

From my syslog:

```
mysql[1663]: ERROR 1577 (HY000) at line 1: Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start
```

I tried this command to find damaged tables:

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair --password
```

but all tables are OK. What's to do now?

**EDIT**

I also tried

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -h localhost -p --verbose --force
```

but everything is OK. Still get the error.

Comment: I have same issue. Were you able to resolve this? If yes, how?

Comment: Run "mysql_upgrade" on the server, then restart mysql service, this help my. https://help.navicat.com/hc/en-us/articles/218283617-1577-Cannot-proceed-because-system-tables-used-by-Event-Scheduler-where-found-damaged-at-server-start

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, altough I didn't notice any errors or problems, I got those warnings. They seemed harmless.

I use MariaDB Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian and your command fixed the issue perfectly:

```
 mysql_upgrade -u root -h localhost -p --verbose --force
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of R&D finally i found solution...........

Basically its happen with mysql 5.7.10 version or earlier versions.

I was getting this error with event table(Mysql event scheduler).
solution-
click on start menu => search for Mysql installer => click on upgrade=> upgrade all mysql => it's really work.............!

Answer (score 0):

I use Navicat for structure synchronisation and it's usually hassle-free, but with this problem I wasn't able to correct the base issue on shared hosting. Unticking 'Compare events' under 'Options' on the screen for selection of Source and Target allowed the structure synch to proceed unhindered.